# The right way to copy map elements

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to remember specific elements of the map to access them later in the code. My map is:

```
map<double, map<string, double>> buf;
```

The map is huge and I need to know the efficient "less-memory-consumption" way to copy some elements from this map during the loop.

Is it better to store pointers or iterators? How do I do it?

Thanks in Advance.

**UPD:**
The map is about ~5000 elements.
Actually I copy them from iterators right now, but want to know if there is a better way

**UPD2:**
I created a vector of iterators and was able to store iterators of above map. But is this a right way for me? I need just select specific elements from the map.

```
vector<map<double, map<string, double>>::const_iterator> tbuf;
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What code are you using now? What is your problem? How much is "huge"? Why do you need the most efficient copy?

Comment: What does storing pointers or iterators have to do with copying elements?

Comment: @otibom updated my post a little. Actually I just wanted to know some sort of right way of doing this. There is not a problem for me just copying iterators, but anyway. :)

Comment: @stefaanv nothing. i need this just to "mark" specific elements

Comment: 5000 elements is tiny, TBH. But since you have a map of maps, "5000 elements" is ambiguous. On an unrelated note, `double` is very rarely a correct map key. `buf[1.0/3.0]` and `buf[7.0/21.0]` may or may not be the same element.

Comment: @MSalters I know about double. I have to use it, 'cause have other's people code already in double. I know, it's bad. I just need to understand if storing a vector of iterators is right way or not. Is this more memory efficient than copying each element?

Comment: @MSalters, so the case is: some massive map. we need to mark some how some elements in this map to access them later in the code. We can do it by just storing a vector of key-values of double or storing iterators. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your map values are maps themselves, copying those inner maps will be quite expensive. It's probably *slightly* cheaper to use pointers to the inner maps than to use iterator, but both are significantly cheaper than copying the inner maps.

However, whether you use pointers or iterators, make sure that they're not invalidated. The referenced inner maps must stay alive.

Comment: thanks. And what is the code to store pointers on this? I think this could save me

Comment: `vector<map<double, map<string, double>> const*> tbuf;`

Comment: thanks. and how do i push_back pointer on a specific element of the map?

Comment: @tomas.berg: You may want to reread your C++ tutorial - it's just `tbuf.push_back(&the_element_you_want)`.

Comment: this doesn't work in VS 2010 `tbuf.push_back(&the_element_you_want)`

Comment: I hope you didn't try literally that !

Comment: sure not :)
well, for example, we have `map<double, double> buf;` then pushing back reference will be like: `tbuf.push_back(&buf[0])` ?

Comment: @tomas.berg: Obviously the types have to match! Read those error messages. You really should get back to your C++ tutorial; this is basic stuff.

Comment: listent. I've done a lot of things in other languages. I know about matching types. I think the question is very simple for you. Let's start from scratch. This code doesn't work:
`map<int, double> mov;
mov[0] = 1.2;
mov[1] = 1.1;
vector<map<int, double>const *>tbuf;
tbuf.push_back(&mov[0]);`

Comment: @tomas.berg: That `buf` example doesn't have a map-in-map. The value type is just `double.` Thus `tbuf` should be just `vector<double*>`.